Meta tag for defining scope of the site?
There's a few questions on Meta already which have to do with defining the scope of this site:

What is our site NOT about?
What's "Too basic" or "General reference" for this site?
Are questions about Human Computer Interaction (HCI) research on or off topic?

I think these all deserve a meta-tag, something like scope-definition. What say everyone else?

Borrowing from other sites, I would use (and have used) scope.

Stack Overflow
User Experience

However, there doesn't seem to be a cross-site consensus:

Programmers uses the rather elaborate on-topic-definition


I like [meta-tag:scope] but will wait for others to weigh in / upvote before going on a mass-retag. Well, okay, it's like 3 questions, so a min-retag :-)

4 questions including this one. ;p P.s. I don't see the benefit of [tag:scope-definition] over [tag:scope]. Well, I could see a difference. This question could be tagged [tag:scope-definition], and the others [tag:scope]. :)

Scope is what I've used before and I've added it to my "not about" question
